# Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server (RDS) redirected printers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm sure this has come up a million times but i'm looking for a quick answer / solution. I have a client that uses a database program that creates an .ini file for printer settings. The problem is that everytime the enduser logs in her printer is redirected to a "TSXXX" port. this port is constantly changing which is of course normal, but each time she logs in since it has changed the .ini file entry for the printer is incorrect as it has changed. The EU then has to go through the whole printer setup each time she logs in to the TS. Is there a way to statically assign the port? or some how make it constant so each time she log in the port remains the same?

Comment: If it's not possible, can you share her printer out and install it on the 2008R2 server?

Answer (score 0):

The ugly: make a batch that find the port and update the ini file at logon.

Exemple of script to parse printer (vbscript) (it set default printer to MYSPECIALPRINTER):
use objprinter attributes (Path i think) to get tsclient path

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")
    For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
        '''wscript.echo ("Imprimante : " & objPrinter.Name & VbCrLf)
        If (left(LCase(objPrinter.name),4) = "MYSPECIALPRINTER") then

            objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(objPrinter.Name)
''wscript.echo ("Imprimante : " & objPrinter.Name & VbCrLf)

        End If

    Next
```